# PHP registration form not sending data to MySQL database

Tags: php, mysql, database, registration

So I am trying to create a log in system for my website.
When I manually insert a user I can log in fine and my database also sees that I am logged in.
But when I try to register a new user I get send to the 'registration successful' page.
Although the information I inserted were never send to my database.

Here are the codes:

Connection:

```
    <?php
    include_once 'psl-config.php'; 
    $mysqli = new mysqli (HOST, USER, PASSWORD, DATABASE);
    ?>
```

Config:

```
    <?php
    /**
     * These are the database login details
     */  
    define("HOST", "localhost");     // The host you want to connect to.
    define("USER", "username");    // The database username. 
    define("PASSWORD", "password");    // The database password. 
    define("DATABASE", "database");    // The database name.

    define("CAN_REGISTER", "any");
    define("DEFAULT_ROLE", "member");

    define("SECURE", FALSE);    // FOR DEVELOPMENT ONLY!!!!
    ?>
```

Registration code:

```
<?php
include_once 'db_connect.php';
include_once 'psl-config.php';

$error_msg = "";

if (isset($_POST['username'], $_POST['email'], $_POST['p'])) {
    // Sanitize and validate the data passed in
    $username = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'username', FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
    $email = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'email', FILTER_SANITIZE_EMAIL);
    $email = filter_var($email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL);
    if (!filter_var($email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)) {
        // Not a valid email
        $error_msg .= '<p class="error">The email address you entered is not valid</p>';
    }

    $password = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'p', FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
    if (strlen($password) != 128) {
        // The hashed pwd should be 128 characters long.
        // If it's not, something really odd has happened
        $error_msg .= '<p class="error">Invalid password configuration.</p>';
    }

    // Username validity and password validity have been checked client side.
    // This should should be adequate as nobody gains any advantage from
    // breaking these rules.
    //

    $prep_stmt = "SELECT id FROM members WHERE email = ? LIMIT 1";
    $stmt = $mysqli->prepare($prep_stmt);

    if ($stmt) {
        $stmt->bind_param('s', $email);
        $stmt->execute();
        $stmt->store_result();

        if ($stmt->num_rows == 1) {
            // A user with this email address already exists
            $error_msg .= '<p class="error">A user with this email address already exists.</p>';
        }
    } else {
        $error_msg .= '<p class="error">Database error</p>';
    }

    // TODO: 
    // We'll also have to account for the situation where the user doesn't have
    // rights to do registration, by checking what type of user is attempting to
    // perform the operation.

    if (empty($error_msg)) {
        // Create a random salt
        $random_salt = hash('sha512', uniqid(openssl_random_pseudo_bytes(16), TRUE));

        // Create salted password 
        $password = hash('sha512', $password . $random_salt);
        // Insert the new user into the database 
        if ($insert_stmt = $mysqli->prepare("INSERT INTO members ($username, $email, $password,$salt) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?)")) {
            $insert_stmt->bind_param('ssss', $username, $email, $password, $random_salt);
            // Execute the prepared query.
            if (! $insert_stmt->execute()) {
                header('Location: ../error.php?err=Registration failure: INSERT');
            }
        }
        header('Location: ./register_success.php');
    }
}
```

I have no idea what I am doing wrong as I am following this:
http://www.wikihow.com/Create-a-Secure-Login-Script-in-PHP-and-MySQL

Comment: What is your registration script?

Comment: I added the registration script.

Comment: Take a closer look at your resulting `INSERT` statement and [how it’s supposed to be](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/insert.html).

Comment: I am looking at it and I can't figure it out. I tried doing this:         if ($insert_stmt = $mysqli->prepare "INSERT INTO members".
        "(username, email, password, salt)"
        "VALUES". 
        "('$username' , '$email', $'password', $'salt')"; . But then again I am no expert here.

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the tutorial, I didn't notice a closing `?>` on some of the code samples. On `psl-config.php` and `db_connect.php`, did you include the `?>` at the end of the file? If not, add them and see if the thing works. Also, in functions.php, add `include_once 'db_connect.php';` below the line that says `include_once 'psl-config.php';`. This might not be an issue, but better safe than sorry. Hope this helps.

Comment: I closed the codes but that didn't help. I also added the 'include_once 'db_connect.php' script.

Answer (score 0):

Hi there try this : `mysqli_connect()` instead of `new mysqli()`

Code as follows :

```
$conn = mysqli_connect($DBServer, $DBUser, $DBPass, $DBName);

// check connection if connection success you would not get anything or else you will get
if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
  trigger_error('Database connection failed: '  . mysqli_connect_error(), SOME_ERROR);
}
```

Comment: I could try that if it goes wrong again.
When I re-pasted the code from the tutorial it suddenly worked.

Comment: @coldy, he can't. [He has 1 Rep](http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/vote-up). You shouldn't beg for upvotes.

Comment: @Andy Sorry then wont ask :D